# Is there a way to lazily load static json during Angular6 routing?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I've got an Angular6 app that is being built as more of a framework for internal apps.  The header / footer / major navigation will be shared, but each app (feature module) should have internal flows separate from each other.  For example one feature might be purchasing, another might be onboarding, another might be a sales dashboard. They're very different from each other.

What I'm trying to do is come up with a declarative way to define known configurations for each feature.  For example, the minor navigation (page to page within a feature), top level header title, and various other context related data points.  My initial thought was to have them defined as JSON within each feature, which works great except I now have to import every feature's config regardless of whether a user navigates, or even has access to, that feature.

I've already got the context service set up that is checking the URL on navigation and setting some items, but again, it has to import all possible configs using this at the top of that service.

```
import { fooConfig } from '@foo\foo.config';
import { barConfig } from '@bar\bar.config';
import { bazConfig } from '@baz\baz.config';
```

So the question is: Is there a way for me to check the URL on navigation, and within that subscription, pick up the config from the correct file without pre-maturely importing them?  Or maybe I can use the module to express / declare those options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updateConfig(feature: string) {
   import(`../configs/${feature}.config.json`).then(cfg => {
      this._currentConfig$.next(cfg);
   });
}
```

The above snippet shows what I came up with.  It turns out WebPack can't digest the @ paths you normally use on imports and you also can't use fully variable paths.  All possible options for the module package must have some common part of the path.  I ended up moving my configs from `@foo\foo.config.ts` to `@core\configs\foo.config.json`.  Which makes them less modular because now core is holding their config, but it makes the module lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Using Typescript's [Dynamic Import Expressions](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2018/01/14/typescript-2-4-dynamic-import-expressions) might be a viable option in your case..

```
let config;
switch (val) {
  case 'foo': config = await import('@foo\foo.config'); break;
  case 'bar': config = await import('@bar\bar.config'); break;
  case 'baz': config = await import('@baz\baz.config'); break;
}
```

Though, as far as I know, there's now way at the time of writing to use variables for the import string (e.g. `await import(path)`).

Comment: I tried that already and maybe I did something wrong, but it's telling me it can't find the file requested.  Maybe because I'm using variables, but they log/debug correctly.

Comment: As mentioned, using variables is not support (by now).